# How to trigger redux action in react componentDidUpdate method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have following action in redux `action.js` file,

```js
export const removeActiveLayer = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
    type: REMOVE_ACTIVE_LAYER,
    payload: id,
  });
};
```

my `reducer.js` file is as below,

```js
    case REMOVE_ACTIVE_LAYER:
      return {
        ...state,
        activeLayers: state.activeLayers.filter((l) => action.payload !== l.id),
      };
```

I tried to remove the layer from the `RemoveLayer.js` file as below,

```
this.props.removeLayer(55);
```

The layer is removed successfully. There is no issue. My question is, How can I get that `id=55` from another file `Layers.js`?

I have tried to get it in `ComponentDidUpdateProps` as below,

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { removeActiveLayer } = this.props;

    if (removeActiveLayer) {
      console.log(removeActiveLayer);
    }
}
```

It is just a function, but actually, I need a removed id. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since at state you already have `activeLayers`, just simply add a new sub state called `lastRemovedLayer`. Your state will look like this:

```
state = {
    // others,
    activeLayers: [],
    lastRemovedLayer: null, // it will be your layer id
}
```

then at reducer

```
case REMOVE_ACTIVE_LAYER:
    return {
        ...state,
        activeLayers: state.activeLayers.filter((l) => action.payload !== l.id),
        lastRemovedLayer: l.id
    };
```

Now you can access this last removed layer in any component at any moment/lifecycle you wish

Comment: Excellent, I added `mapStateToProps` event for getting the `lastremovedLayer` and in componentDidUpdate method for further action, `if (this.props.lastRemovedLayer !== prevProps.lastRemovedLayer)`

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the removed `id` in redux state as well if you want to access it in the some other component.

So your `reducer.js` file would become:

```
case REMOVE_ACTIVE_LAYER:
      return {
        ...state,
        removedId: action.payload,
        activeLayers: state.activeLayers.filter((l) => action.payload !== l.id),
      };
```

And now you can access the `removedId` as a prop from any other component you want:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { removedId } = this.props;

    if (removedId) {
      console.log(removedId);
    }
}
```